# OpenGL cohabitation of shader and drawing command

Tags: c++, opengl

In my application, I use OpenGL to draw many shapes using the classic Shader + VAO + many VBO and call glDrawArrays(...)

It is working well but to implement axis visualization, I try to use OpenGL commands.

I came up with this code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

WhenPaint(); //The function which loop around all object and draw using proper VAO and shaders

//Here I start use OpenGL draw commands to draw my axis
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(&(camera.GetProjectionMatrix(Upp::Sizef{sizeW,sizeH})[0][0])); //Setting up projection

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(&(camera.GetViewMatrix()[0][0])); //Setting up viewMatrix

if(ShowAxis)GLDrawFunction::PaintAxis(0, 0, 0,200); //a function that draw axis
```

This work but only if I comment the WhenPaint() function...

Here you have the view without the WhenPaint() function:

[image: Without WhenPaint()]

And here you have the view when I use WhenPaint() (before or after the OpenGL Draw commands do not matter) :

[image]

**Is it possible to make these two ways of drawing things work together?**

Comment: Which OpenGL version are you using? The axis code only works without shaders (fixed function pipeline). It's a bad idea to mix shaders (core profile) with fixed function code.

Comment: working with OpenGL 4.6 but I ensure my code is compatible with atleast OpenGL 4.0. Ok so if it is a bad idea then I will use normal way ot draw axis. Thanks @BDL